# Python3 Slicing, TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, slice

I want to extract information from .json format through API for each element in array.

I tried to use below code but get me an error.

```
# Get the response from the API endpoint.
response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")
data = response.json()
print(data["people"][0:2]["name"])
```

I would expect to see every name listed instead of an error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

I know there is error in [O:2] array. Can anyone help ?

Comment: You have to iterate over the array containing dicts with key `name`, try running `names = [di['name'] for di in data["people"][0:2]]`, here `names` will store list(array) of `names` that you're to get.

Comment: can you show an example of your json

Answer (score 3):

`data["people"][0:2]` return list `[{'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Alexey Ovchinin'}, {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Nick Hague'}]`

you should iterate list

```
name = [x['name'] for x in data["people"][0:2]]
print(name)
```

O/P:

```
['Alexey Ovchinin','Nick Hague']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `data["people"][0:2]` is a list (try `type(data["people"][0:2]` in ipython), you cannot use a string index to refer to its elements.

If what you want is the list of name for the people indexed from 0 to 2 (2 not included) in the list, what you want is:

```py
print( [x["name"] for x in data["people"][0:2] )
```